# Numpy as a library in a django project

Tags: python, django, numpy, scipy

I am not able to put numpy in libs folder in a `Django` project. I dont want to install that on my machine as everywhere it is done. When i put the numpy folder in the lib folder it gives the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Ketan\Desktop\NES\libs\numpy\__init__.py", line 128, in <module
>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python intepreter from there.
```

I've also put `Scipy` folder in the libs folder.

I have used `PIL` the same way and it works just fine. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong??

Comment: Im pretty sure you would need to do `python setup.py configure --prefix /home/some/lib/folder/ & python setup.py install` in the nupy folder that contains setup.py

Answer (score 0):

download the numpy source folder, the one with setup.py in it.

copy this folder to your remote host using sftp or something ...

ssh to your remote server

login

type :

```
$> mkdir /lib
$> mkdir /lib/pythonX.Y ; x,y is pyversion
$> mkdir /lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
$> cd numpy_folder_with_setup_py
$> python setup.py install --prefix=~
```

should install numpy to your prefix
now just add

```
$> echo "export PYTHONPATH=~/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/ .bashrc
```

you will need to log out and back in

```
$> echo $PYTHONPATH
```

make sure it includes your custom library path

```
$> python -c "import numpy"
```

if there is no error you have successfully setup numpy :)

note: you may need to set your sys.path variable to include this folder in a different manner if your webserver skips your .bashrc initialization

Comment: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat.
I searched around and the solution is to have Visual C++..